# Which technology is used in a Liferay web content portlet?

Tags: liferay, portlet, webcontent

In order to create web content, a web content portlet is used. What technology is behind this portlet? What was used to develop this portlet? JSP, JSF, Struts, Icefaces, or any thing else?

Moreover, is there a link to download it separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's using JSP, Java (using Liferay MVCPortlet) possibly some Alloy UI, and Struts 1 (as it's used throughout Liferay).

You can't download it separately, but the source code is there in the Liferay source archives. You just have to dig out Web Content Specific parts.

Comment: Additional information for inspecting the sourcecode: For historical reasons the WebContent parts is named "Journal*" - so look for the API and classes starting with this name.

Comment: No worries, happy to help! If you could also accept my answer (if you think it's correct) I'd be much obliged. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The source can be found and downloaded here:
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal

You will find the java source files under: \portal-service\src\com\liferay\portlet\journal

And the jsp pages under: \portal-web\docroot\html\portlet\journal